# CStatic DrawItem method getting called too freequently after creating a child window

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, mfc, dialog, sdi

I have a Image viewer application window using layout splitters.
I am drawing the bitmap on a dialog inside a splitter using a custom image control

```
class CPictureCtrl :
    public CStatic
{
public:


    .
    .

protected:
    virtual void PreSubclassWindow();

    //Draws the Control
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
    virtual BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);

private:

    //Internal image stream buffer
    IStream* m_pStream;

    //Control flag if a pic is loaded
    BOOL m_bIsPicLoaded;

    //GDI Plus Token
    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
};
```

Inside the DrawItem() method, I take GDI+ graphics from lpDrawItemStruct and paint the image.

Everything works fine, but when I open a child window to the dialog where I have this control, the image gets painted over my popup window.

Is there a way I can bring the popup window to the front.

full source of the control can be found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24969/An-MFC-picture-control-to-dynamically-show-picture?fid=1183733&df=90&mpp=25&noise=1&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Expanded&spc=Relaxed&fr=1

Comment: Does the parent dialog have the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style?

Comment: No, WS_CLIPCHILDREN is set to false.

Comment: What happens if you set it to true?